# Jacques Lacan's Structuralism - Terminology

Tags: reference-request, terminology, structuralism, lacan

I'm doing a research on Jacques Lacan's Structuralism. I've been told that he had some believes, or ideas about subject.
So, I'm looking for the terminology of Lacan's Structuralism, as the first step of my research.

Any good sources suggestions?

Comment: there's a wiki site dedicated to lacan, that is really amazing! unfortunately i cannot find it, may be moribund now. no idea who was compiling it, but yea

Comment: @user3293056 you may be thinking of Lacanian Ink's site? (Not exactly a wiki but lots of articles/resources/media/etc.) http://www.lacan.com/

Comment: @JosephWeissman i meant "no subject" but yeah that looks pretty good too

Comment: Why do you regard Lacan as a representative of structuralism instead of poststructuralism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good place to start would be the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy's article [Jacques Lacan](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lacan/) as well as the Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy's article [Jacques Lacan (1901—1981)](http://www.iep.utm.edu/lacweb/#SH4c). The SEP article has a very comprehensive bibliography listing both primary and secondary literature relating to Lacan's ideas. The IEP article has an entire section devoted to Lacan's ideas about "subject" which starts by asserting:

> [Lacan argues that the subject is "the subject of the signifier." One meaning of this claim at least is that there is no subject proper that is not a speaking subject, who has been subject to castration and the law of the father. I shall return to this formulation below, though, for its full meaning only becomes evident when another crucial claim that Lacan makes concerning the subject is properly examined. This is the apparently contradictory claim that the subject as such, at the same time as being a linguistic subject, lacks a signifier. There is no subject without language, Lacan wants to say, and yet the subject constitutively lacks a place in language.](http://www.iep.utm.edu/lacweb/#SH4c)

A primary resource that discusses the topics in that section would be *[The Seminar of Jacques Lacan: The Ethics of Psychoanalysis (Vol. Book VII)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393316130)*. Additionally, *[Ecrits](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393329259)* is probably Lacan's most important collection of writings that you should read if you are planning on understanding his work; it contains many of his writings including the seminar mentioned above. As you will see in the bibliographies, [Zizek](http://www.iep.utm.edu/zizek/) has written extensively on Lacan and is probably the most ubiquitous (for better or for worse) contemporary philosopher that writes on the topic. See his book *[Looking Awry: An Introduction to Jacques Lacan through Popular Culture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/026274015X)*.

Answer (score 0):

There was a ridiculous wiki site called "no subject" which I can no longer find. You can find an older version of it on archived [here](https://archive.org/details/wiki-nosubjectcom). There are also dictionaries available, in print, this by Evans

[image]

and I think (unsure) there may be another avilable.

I would recommend either, as it seems that Lacanians aren't hostile to encyclopedias for beginners!